# Running apex code from Force.com CLI

Tags: commandline

I've quickly searched through this site and Google, but I did not find the answer.
I started to use new **Force.com CLI** on **Windows**, but I faced with trouble that I can't run apex code from command line (I tried Cygwin and cmd shells).

The trouble is that the CLI just do nothing. Help says that for running a code I need to type my code and just pres [Control + D], but it seems not working for me.

I tried different keys combinations based on the Wikipedia article about mapping a keyboard shortcuts on different OS as well as random pressing the most known keys combinations. Other commands work normally.

Thanks.

Comment: See also [Equivalent to ^D (in bash) for cmd.exe?](http://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe)

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for your link, yes, I did  it, but it does not work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I observe the same thing.  It just hangs and I have to hit CTRL-C to leave get out of it and nothing happens.  Also, CTRL-Z didn't work.

You can create a file and you can actually just pass the name of the file as a parameter to the `force apex` command as that is one of the supported parameters.

If you run `force help apex` you get the the usage:

[image: force apex usage]

For example, create a file called anonApex.txt in the directory you are in and put `System.debug('hello world');` in it.

Then, from the command line:

C:\path\to\your\dir>force apex anonApex.txt

You get something like:

[image: force apex cmd]

Perhaps it has something to do with detecting, from the command line, an end of transmission or end of file character difference between *nix and Windows.  I wouldn't be surprised if CTRL-D worked on *nix based systems.  Usually it is CTRL-Z on Windows.

I believe my guess at the this to be confirmed.  I found the following issue logged against the Go Programming language:

[Issue 6303: syscall: reading os.Stdin does not treat ^Z as EOF on Windows](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6303&q=EOF&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Release%20Owner%20Repo%20Summary) which looks a lot like what we are observing.

After reading over that issue and related discussions, I think that the handling of CTRL-Z for Windows console apps is not a high priority for the Go Programming language, so it looks like the only way to use the `force apex` command from Windows is with a file input.  CTRL-Z will not work unless the underlying Go Programming language changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, you're my personal hero! I was going to use this feature in build scripts in order to reduce the efforts of my team and I was really upset when found this issue, but your answer brought me back to life. Thank you again.

Comment: @Pavel - No problem.  Glad I could help! :)